# Save User Id in data storage in all table

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, datastore, data-storage

This is my model `Person`

```
public int PersonId { get; set; }

public string FirstName { get; set; }

public string Email { get; set; }

public int CreatedUser { get; set; }
```

`CreatedUser` is for checking which user does an operation in each method and table.
How can I save `UserId` in `CreatedUser` in each method,
especially in the register method?
When a user wants to register, he initially has no User ID. How can I save the user ID?

I heard that I can save it in data storage but how?
All of my other tables should have this property `CreatedUser`.

Comment: You should describe what your storage is actually like if you want someone to be able to answer this.  If you're already using a database you should include the stack.

Comment: How your Register method looks like? While you resgister how many table you need to insert data into? Please share these details in order to investigate your scenario faster.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Its a normal code for register method. my question is not specific for register method. all tables have this property "CretedUser" for checking saving operation with users. I heard I hade to save it on data storage for each operation, but I don't know how?